# I am still confused with Gaussian kernel in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

From the slides http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/kuleuven_svm.pdf, 
$$\min \frac{1}{2}w^Tw $$
subject to $$y_i(w^T\phi(x_i)+b)\ge 1,i=1,\cdots,n$$

I think most people are very familiar with this equation.
I assume $w$ is in the same space of $\phi(x_i)$, in this way, $w^Tw$ always be 1 when uses Gaussian kernel.

$w$ is in feature space, here for Gaussian kernel, it is infinite space. But I think $w=\phi(w')$, $w'$ is in the original space. Then $\phi(w')^T\phi(w')=w^Tw=k(w',w')=1$

and

$\phi(w')^T\phi(x)$ is always be positive if $w'$ exists.

Comment: Why do you believe that $||w||^{2} = w^{T}w$ will be 1?

Comment: @EMS, because $w^Tw=k(w,w)=e^{-\|w-w\|^2/2\sigma^2}$

Comment: Not quite, $w^T w$ is the Euclidean inner product in feature space.  The kernel is a function which takes two vectors in input space and computes the Euclidean inner product in feature space as a function of the input space variables $x_i$.

Comment: @SamLivingstone, ok, $w$ is in feature space, here for Gaussian kernel, it is infinite space. $w^Tw$ is not equal to $k(w,w)$. I was wrong before. But I think $w=\phi(w')$, $w'$ is in the original space. Then $\phi(w')^T\phi(w')=w^Tw=k(w',w')=1$

Comment: @Vivian $\phi$ is not necessarily invertible, so an arbitrary vector, $w$, in the feature space does not necessarily have a pre-image $w'$ in the original space.  In the case of the Gaussian kernel, $\phi$ maps vectors onto the positive orthant of the unit hyper-sphere, and $w$ does not necessarily lie on the unit hyper-sphere (is is an arbitrary weight vector of a linear model) and hence it cannot be expressed as $\phi(w')$.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, Hello, thank you for your answer. I think it helps. But I am a little hard to understand you. I know what you mean roughly. You mean $\phi$ is not 1-1 mapping.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, so do you think $w^Tw$ is a random value?

Comment: @Vivian, I'm not sure what you mean by "random", $w$ is certainly arbitrary (in the sense that it can take on any value).  There is nothing that constrains $w$ to be a vector on the unit hypersphere just because the images of the input patterns are on the unit hyper-sphere.

Comment: I think the issue here is that $w$ is just a weight vector learned over in the feature space. It is not the projection of any particular vector from the original space. (It might be, but even if it is, that's not important). You should think of first moving all of your data to the feature space through $\phi$ and *then* trying to locate a separating hyperplane given by the vector $w$. You are not looking for a weight vector that applies back in the original domain.

Comment: Consider two points on the unit hyper-sphere, one representing a positive pattern and one representing a negative pattern.  We can always find a separating plane, such that the output of the model is +1 for the positive pattern and -1 for the negative pattern (i.e. a maximum margin classifier).  If we now move those two points closer together, we can still make a maximum margin classifier, but the norm of the weights will be higher as the output of the linear classifier has to change more rapidly as a function of the distance in the feature space.  Thus they cannot both have $w^Tw = 1$.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, I am barely know hyper-sphere. I should learn it first then I could understand you.

Comment: @EMS, I have to convince myself there is no $w'$, I can understand there are many. I am hard to accepte none. Thank you.

Comment: @Vivian, for the purposes of the counter example I gave, it would be acceptable to consider $\phi$ mapping points onto the circumference of a circle (as there are only two points).  The inverse of $\phi$ is only defined for points that lie on the circle, and there is no "pre-image" for points in feature space that do not lie on the circle.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, thank you for your another simple explanation. If there are two points, we do not bother to class them. Does you think \phi project points to a surface of a sphere because Gaussian kernel is aRadial basis function kernel? And I guess polynomial kernel is not a 1-1 mapping too.

Comment: @Vivian, for the RBF kernel, $\phi$ may well be a one-to-one mapping, but that does not necessarily imply that there exists a point in the original space that corresponds to every point in the feature space.  Loosely speaking the original space is finite dimensional and the feature space is infinite dimensional, so we can have a one-to-one mapping from original to feature space without using up every point in the feature space.  If we them pick a point elsewhere in the feature space there is no where in the original space that corresponds to it.

Comment: Let $F$ be the feature space defined by $\phi$, for the RBF kernel, this is a manifold embedded in an infinite dimensional space, i.e. $F \subset R^\infty$.  $w$ can be any vector in $R^\infty$, so it isn't necessarily a point in $F$, and so it cannot generally be expressed as $\phi(w')$.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, thank you so much for your answer. I am much more clearer now.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer?
[Better to have a short answer than no answer at
all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/)
Anyone who has a better answer can post it.